# Можно ли добыть целый ПДФ файл в данном случае?

Tags: pdf

Есть ссылка, по типу - http://yakistosviti.com.ua/userfiles/pdf_book/samples/Ukrainska-literatura-Jacenko/slider.html

Используется что-то вроде pdf-flipbook. Можно ли целиком достать ПДФ, не картинками?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

На данном сервисе книги хранятся в формате изображений.
Как вариант скачать их все

Я бы написал небольшой скрипт в моем случае на php

```php
<?php
for ($i=0; $i < 262; $i++) { 
    $a =  file_get_contents("http://yakistosviti.com.ua/userfiles/pdf_book/samples/Ukrainska-literatura-Jacenko/pages/$i.jpg");
    $b = file_put_contents("book/$i.png",$a);
}
```

После прогнал бы спарсенные фото через сервис
https://convert-my-image.com/ImagesToPdf_Ru

Для Вас уже сделал ссылка на скачивание pdf 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OHmY6nYlQ6S7fN-vmvfigchsBAVwtjtD/view?usp=sharing

Будет доступна 1 день

Comment: Супер, спасибо!

Буду использовать.

А разве оно не делает изображения из pdf файла, который лежит на самом сервере? В данном случае, узнать месторасположение самого файла невозможно?